# Is a card considered the same card if it is from a different set?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With the brand new Rivals of Ixalan set coming out soon, I was looking at the card library and I saw they had the [Legion Conquistador](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLegion%20Conquistador%5d) in again. It is exactly the same as the Legion Conquistador from Ixalan, and I want to know if it is considered the same card if it has the same name and effects as another card, but is from a different set? So could I have 8 Legion Conquistadors, 4 from Ixalan and 4 from Rivals of Ixalan? Or are they the same card?

Comment: The _name_ is the only thing that matters, see the other question.

Comment: Have we ever had a card with two different printings in the same standard format? Maybe something like Naturalize or Shatter has had multiple printings but this could be unique.

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are the same card. Cards are determined by their English name, not by any other statistic of the card, including text, art, and set information. For all cards, other then some of the cards in the new unstable set like [Very Cryptic Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%20[Very]%20[Cryptic]%20[Command]), cards with the same English name will have the same effect based on oracle text, though printed text may vary, as newer copies will have the oracle text at the time of printing. There have been cards which are functional reprints, where the effect is the same but the card name is different, like [Dragon Fodder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDragon%20Fodder%5d) and [Krenko's Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrenko%27s%5d%2b%5bCommand%5d), these cards are different cards, as they have different English names, even though everything else about them is identical.

From the comprehensive rules:

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates his or her own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards. A constructed deck may contain any number of basic land cards and no more than four of any card with a particular English name other than basic land cards.

This of course only applies to constructed play, not limited play. If you were playing in the prerelease this past weekend and got one [Legion Conquistador](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLegion%20Conquistador%5d) in both Ixalan packs and in all 4 Rivals of Ixalan packs for a total of six, you are free to play all six copies. (unlikely to happen but possible)

Comment: Please do not edit to replace the link with mtg: format, mtg:format links for cards like very cryptic do not find all results as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are considered the same card. Only their English name matters.

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates his or her own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards. A constructed deck may contain any number of basic land cards and no more than four of any card with a particular English name other than basic land cards.